# Проблемы с CORS в nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

Я сделал простой прокси на nginx который направляет на `localhost:3000`,на 3000 порту у меня запущен React JS. При переходе на главную страницу все нормально, но не выводит данные полученные от сервера другого(`127.0.0.1:8000`) т.к. firefox блокирует их из за CORS. Сама ошибка в консоле браузера:`Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vds/product_order/. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS). Код состояния: (null).`

Добавил в файл конфигурации nginx `add_header` вот так :

```
   server {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        location / {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location ~ \.(gif|png|jpg)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
            root /home/lostik/data/images;
        }
```

Пробовал и дугие варианта по типу if ($request_method), не чего не помогло.
Так же попробовал в коде написать header вот так :

```
    static async get_order_product() {
        const res_product = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vds/product_order/',{
            headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Methods":'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vds/product_order/'}
         })

        return res_product.data
```

Так же безуспешно. Всё это работает на виртуальной машине linux. Можно ли это как то исправить? И надо ли создавать еще прокси сервер для `127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: а пробовали зайти на фронт апп по `127.0.0.1` а не по `localhost`?

Comment: А какое отношение имеет этот nginx к серверу 127.0.0.1:8000?

Comment: @andreymal cors смотрит соответствие домена сайта, если на локальном приложении только 127.0.0.1 стоит в разрешенных, то он может агриться на localhost

Comment: @DmitryKozlov во-первых, cors смотрит соответствие не домена, а origin (протокол + домен + порт), а во-вторых, в данном конкретном случае origin источника запроса ни на что не повлияет, если автор пытается разрешить запросы со всех origin'ов с помощью звёздочки

Comment: @andreymal как я понял из вопроса на нжиниксе только 3000 порт с реактом. А на 8000 отдельный сервис, на который звездочки из конфига нжиникса не влияют

Comment: @DmitryKozlov попробовал с ```127.0.01``` тоже не помогло , но конфиг nginx не менял

Comment: и еще, я отключил CORS в firefox , и всё заработало , значит пока без cors можно будет тестить

Comment: @Lostskill разрешать cors должен именно тот сервер, который отвечает на cors-запросы, то есть в вашем случае 127.0.0.1:8000. Если он никак не связан с nginx, то значит и трогать nginx нет никакого смысла, добавлять cors-заголовки нужно конкретно в сервер 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @andreymal но только вот ответ от 127.0.0.1:8000 приходит валидный, сам браузер блокирует json с данными.

Comment: @Lostskill что вы имеете в виду под фразой «ответ приходит валидный»? В нём есть заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: @andreymal Нет , что странно ведь прокси перенаправляет запрос , без nginx все работало

Comment: @Lostskill как вы определили, что «прокси перенаправляет запрос»? У вас nginx слушает порт 8000 или о чём речь вообще?

Comment: @andreymal Ну как я понял когда я захожу на ```localhost``` , запрос перенаправляется на ```localhost:3000```, и уже в браузере отображает страницу как если бы мы просто зашли на ```localhost:3000```, но вот здесь и проблема что от сервера на ```127.0.0.1:8000``` я толком не могу получить данные когда я нахожусь в ```localhost```

Comment: @Lostskill но запрос-то вы отправляете не на 3000, а на 8000, и если ваш nginx не слушает порт 8000, то значит nginx тут абсолютно ни при чём и ничего не проксируется. Ответ в целом всё тот же — cors-заголовки должен отправлять конкретно сервер 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @andreymal окей , но как тогда сделать так чтобы react отправлял эти заголовки на ```127.0.0.1:8000``` когда обращается к API ?

Comment: @Lostskill вы опять всё перепутали, разрешающие cors-заголовки нужно отправлять не из реакта в 8000, а из 8000 в реакт (точнее в браузер, чтобы он увидел эти cors-заголовки и перестал блокировать json с данными)

Comment: @andreymal действительно , я поменял на бэкенде ```CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS``` и заработало , спасибо